# How do I set argument types in React-Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-typescript

`({ title, subTitle, image })` are all 3 defaulting to `any` type and I should be able to set them to a `string`
unless there is a more specific type to set the image's type to an `URL`?
I'm just using the **default tabs template** from **Expo**. which does use **TypeScript.**
I'd probably prefer to set them **inline**, but have no objection to trying an **interface** either.. I thought it was just
colon string

```
: string
```

but I must be missing something in the syntax because so far it's not been liking that.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import colors from '../constants/Colors'
import AppText from './AppText'

// interface AppCardProps {
//   title: string;
//   subTitle: string;
//   image: string;
// }


export default function AppCard({ title, subTitle, image }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.image}
        source={image} />
      <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
        <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
        <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    marginBottom: 20,
    overflow: "hidden",
    // width: 360,
    width: "90%",

  },
  detailsContainer: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  image: {
    // width: 360,
    // width: "100%",
    height: 200,
    // resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  subTitle: {
    color: colors.secondary,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to React Native, but TypeScript in general.

```js
interface AppCardProps {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
  image: string;
}

export default function AppCard({ title, subTitle, image }: AppCardProps) {
  // ...
}
```

or using the `React.FC` type

```js
import React from 'react';

interface AppCardProps {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
  image: string;
}

const AppCard: React.FC<AppCardProps> = ({ title, subTitle, image }) => {
  // ...
}

export default AppCard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an other way you could imagine it. I actually prefer it this way where you just have the props be called props instead of going into a destructuring assignment syntax where you strip the fields off. I feel there's a benefit in having your component actually refer to props.title and props.subTitle, etc. It also helps when I have to refactor props and I don't want to confuse them with other variables or useState variables with similar names.. Having them all just be called "props.title" makes me know I'm definitely hitting the title that is coming via properties.

And, as a side benefit, when you do it this way it's fairly straightforward to see that the props variable has the property shape you defined.

```
interface AppCardProps {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
  image: string;
}

export default function AppCard(props: AppCardProps) {
  // ...
}
```